# What is the history of Eastern and Western Armenian dialects?

Tags: historical-linguistics, comparative-linguistics, dialects, armenian

Are there any regular phonetical correspondences between grammatical patterns of both dialects? Which one is thought to be the 'real' Armenian?

When and how did the dialects split? Is [Western Armenian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Armenian) an offspring of the [Eastern dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Armenian), or did the dialects appear during a synchronous process?

Comment: I believe the differences are greater than between British and American English. My friends in Yerevan can tell instantly when a Western Armenian speaker walks by if they are speaking. I was very surprised to read on the internet in recent weeks in a forum or possibly YouTube comments some Eastern Armenian speakers making abusive comments toward Western Armenian speakers about their dialect!

Comment: @hippietrail: so is the Eastern Armenian considered to be 'more Armenian' than its Western variety?

Comment: Is British English considered 'more English' than American? Linguists certainly would never consider either 'more Armenian' that the other - both are Armenian, and so both are equally Armenian.

Comment: @Manjusri: I don't know - it's just an anecdote. I only had a comment and not an answer. But let me publicize this question to my Armenian friends on Facebook ...

Comment: @hippietrail That'd be great.

Comment: One portion of your question is very confusing. You ask: "Are there any regular phonetical correspondences between grammatical patterns of both dialects?" Are you looking for regular phonetic correspondences? Or are you looking for regular grammatical similarities? In either case, the answer to that is of course there are. They are related dialects; there's going to be a massive amount of correspondences in terms of phonology and morphosyntax.

Comment: @Manjusri: Well my friend Vahagn has contributed an answer, but not a very detailed one. I suppose Stack Exchange is not his forte. He does most of the work on Armenian and Old Armenian on Wiktionary.

Answer (score 3):

Eastern and  Western Armenian developed from Old Armenian, not from each other. Both are equally Armenian. I don't know the answers to the rest of your questions.